# How to ask user for ONLY one word string input and produce error prompt in a try-catch block

Tags: java, string

EDIT: I figured it out! I got rid of the try-catch block because it just didn't work the way I wanted it to. The code below is my final one. Thank you to everyone who responded to this question.

I am trying to code a to-do list program. One function of this program is to search for the entries inside the string array. The user should only input a ONE WORD keyword so if the user inputs more than one word or none, a prompt should show telling the user to try again. The code I've written so far is inside a try-catch statement. Using next() scanner only takes the first word and disregards the rest when inputting a multiple-word keyword, instead of producing an Exception. Here is my code for it:

````
case 2:
                    String searchKeyword;
                    
                    
                    int success = 0;
                    
                    while(success==0) {
                        System.out.print(">> Enter 1 keyword: ");
                        searchKeyword = sc.nextLine();
                        
                        String splitSearchKeyword[] = searchKeyword.split(" ");
                        
                        if (splitSearchKeyword.length == 1) {
                            if(Quinones_Exer2.searchToDoList(searchKeyword, todoList)==-1) {
                                System.out.println(">> No item found with that keyword!");
                                System.out.println();
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println(">> Found one item!");
                                System.out.println("("+(Quinones_Exer2.searchToDoList(searchKeyword, todoList)+1)+")"+" "+todoList[Quinones_Exer2.searchToDoList(searchKeyword, todoList)]);
                                System.out.println();
                            }
                            success++;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println(">> Please input a single word keyword!");
                            System.out.println();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }```
````

Comment: Read an entire line of input and then use `String.split`.  Much simpler.

Comment: @JeffHolt Unfortunately, I am required to produce the error prompt whenever a user inputs a keyword that is more than one word or none at all.

Comment: What would stop you from interrogating the size of the array produced by `String.split`?

Comment: I agree with @JeffHolt - read a line, split into words (split by whitespace), give an error if there is more than one word.  Simple, and addresses the requirements. directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Scanner.nextLine()** then split the supplied string. If the length of array is greater than 1 or the supplied string is empty then issue an invalid entry message and have the User enter the string over again:

```
while(tries2 == 0) {
    searchKeyword  = "";
    while (searchKeyword.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("Enter 1 keyword: ");
        searchKeyword = sc.nextLine().trim();
        if (searchKeyword.isEmpty() || searchKeyword.split("\\s+").length > 1) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Entry! {" + searchKeyword 
                             + "You must supply a single Key Word!");
            searchKeyword = "";
        }
    }
    tries2++;
    // ... The rest of your code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs of [Scanner.next()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()):

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

You would need to call `next()` again to get the the rest of the input.

Much simpler would be to use [Scanner.nextLine()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) to get entire line and then use [String.split()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) with whatever delimiter you are using to get an array of all inputted keywords.

**Edit:** [Scanner.next(pattern)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.lang.String)) may do what you are looking for. It throws `InputMismatchException` if the input does not match provided pattern(regex). Example:

```
scanner.next("^[a-zA-Z]+$")
```

This requires the entire line to consist of lower and/or upper case letters and nothing else.

Comment: I don't think this would fix my problem as I only need one word keyword as user input. Anything less or more than that should produce an Exception that will be caught by the catch block.

Comment: @qwertyboi Check edit for the method which throws required exception. Btw the first approach can also achieve the same, you need to check the resulting array length, and handle it appropriately, as a bonus there is no need to catch exceptions.

Comment: I tried the regex(if I'm not mistaken) string pattern you provided. now it just produces the error prompt even if I enter a single word input

Comment: Most probably you have some leftover previous inputs, which have not been read by the scanner, in this case the pattern won't match. You can validate the regex in any tool you prefer, it certainly works for single line consisting only of letters. I prefer [https://regexr.com/](https://regexr.com/), [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) is also good, or something else.